# Python IndentationError: expected an indented block in a script of mine

Tags: python

I am writing a script that gives back the IP from a website. I have written it successfully, but now I am trying to add some kind of verification to the IP itself ,in order to see if it is down.  It is giving me this error:

```
c:\Users\PC\Desktop>getip.py
  File "C:\Users\PC\Desktop\getip.py", line 21
    conn.connect((ip, port))
       ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

Here is the script :

```
# AUTHOR : G19
# Version : 1.0.0v

import time, socket, os, sys, string

print ("#####################################################")
print ("#     SCRIPT : GETIP.PY                             #")
print ("#     AUTHOR : G19                                  #")
print ("#     VERSION: 1.0.0b                               #")
print ("#####################################################")
print ("")

host = raw_input('WEBSITE LINK : ')
ip = socket.gethostbyname(host)
conn = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
port = 80


def getip():
    try:
        conn.connect((ip, port))
        conn.send("Sending packet confirmation")
    except:   
        print ("")
        print ("#####################################################")
        print ("#     STATUS : DOWN                                 #")
        print ("#     IP: " + ip + "                                #")
        print ("#####################################################")
        print ("")
    print ("")
    print ("#####################################################")
    print ("#     STATUS : UP                                   #")
    print ("#     IP: " + ip + "                                #")
    print ("#####################################################")
    print ("")    
    return

getip()
```

Comment: I guess you have mixed tabs and spaces

Comment: Your pasted code is OK, but python tells you there is a problem with the indention at line 21. Check if there is the same distance, and use either tabs or spaces for indention. It helps much.

Comment: the thing is that the spaces appear correctly in sublime text editor, the error is in the line containing the line next to the try:

Comment: @user2090618: Select the lines before too; the `try` has a continuous line, not dots..

Answer (score 2):

You are mixing tabs and spaces. The `try:` line is indented with a tab, the next line with spaces; my editor shows tabs as a line, spaces as dots, when selected:

[image: tab circled]

Python expands tabs to **8** spaces, so to Python, there is no difference between the lines.

Don't mix tabs and spaces. Configure your editor to always expand indentation to spaces, and replace all existing tabs with spaces. PEP 8 (the python styleguide) [recommends spaces over tabs](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#tabs-or-spaces), as does the [Google Python styleguide](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/pyguide.html#Indentation).